# Javascript functions and setting values depending on a checkbox

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to recreate this Javascript snippet found here (you have to scroll down a bit to where it says **Get Started**: [Javascript Snippet](https://www.redirecthealth.com/self-employed-health/)

I recreated a version in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/lyss-js/pen/xxERrpe). But it's not working properly. I basically am trying to get the values to return to their original values before the tobacco/medshare options were selected. However, right now, they don't go back and I can't figure it out :/

**HTML File**

```
<div class="w-full md:w-1/2 p-16 flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-1 text-gray-dark">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="bg-white rounded-18 p-16 relative z-1">
               <ul class="list-reset text-16 font-bold flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 flex flex-col justify-between">
                  <li>
                     <div class="mb-18 text-center flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
                        <h4 class="flex justify-center items-center leading-none text-blue-light" style="margin-bottom: 0rem;"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-24 md:text-48 -ml-14 md:-ml-20">$</span> <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 h1_xl2" id="price">319</span></h4>
                        <p class="text-18 font-normal" style="margin-bottom: 1rem">PER MONTH</p>
                     </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="mb-4 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
                     <div class="mb-8">
                        <label class="check_box">
                           <input type="radio" id="m" name="radio" value="319" onclick="setPrice()"> 
                           <div class="flex justify-between flex-wrap text-14 sm:text-16 text-blue-light"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-12 sm:text-16">Myself</span> <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 ml-4" id="myselfSmoke">$319/mo.</span></div>
                           <span class="radiomark"></span>
                        </label>
                     </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="mb-4 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
                     <div class="mb-8">
                        <label class="check_box">
                           <input type="radio" id="ms" name="radio" value="639" onclick="setPrice()"> 
                           <div class="flex justify-between flex-wrap text-14 sm:text-16"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-12 sm:text-16">Myself + Spouse</span> <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 ml-4" id="msSmoke">$639/mo.</span></div>
                           <span class="radiomark"></span>
                        </label>
                     </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="mb-4 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
                     <div class="mb-8">
                        <label class="check_box">
                           <input type="radio" id="mc" name="radio" value="639" onclick="setPrice()"> 
                           <div class="flex justify-between flex-wrap text-14 sm:text-16"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-12 sm:text-16">Myself + Children</span> <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 ml-4" id="mcSmoke">$639/mo.</span></div>
                           <span class="radiomark"></span>
                        </label>
                     </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="mb-4 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
                     <div class="mb-8">
                        <label class="check_box">
                           <input type="radio" id="mf" name="radio" value="899" onclick="setPrice()"> 
                           <div class="flex justify-between flex-wrap text-14 sm:text-16"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-12 sm:text-16">Myself + Family</span> <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 ml-4" id="mfSmoke">$899/mo.</span></div>
                           <span class="radiomark"></span>
                        </label>
                     </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 p-8 -mx-8 rounded-6 bg-blue-light">
                     <label class="check_box">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="areYouASmoker" id="smoker" onclick="setSmokerPrice()"> 
                        <div class="text-white">
                           <p class="text-14 leading-none text-center mr-32 md:mr-0">Yes. A member uses tobacco.</p>
                           <p class="text-12 leading-none font-normal text-center mr-32">($75 surcharge)</p>
                        </div>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                     </label>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-gray-lightest px-16 pb-16 pt-48 -mt-32">
               <label class="check_box">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="sayNoToPlus" class="bg-white" id="sayNoToPlus" onclick="setMedicalSharePrice()"> 
                  <div>
                     <p class="leading-thin text-14 text-center mr-24">I have my own <br>Medical Cost Share / Insurance</p>
                  </div>
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
               </label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="mt-16">
      <!----> 
      <p class="text-16 mb-16 max-w-500 mx-auto text-center disclaimer">Members age 65 and over are not eligible for Medical Cost Share. Tobacco users will incur an extra $75 surcharge</p>
      <div class="max-w-330 mx-auto text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-solid circle btn-bordered border-thin ld_button_5fd7072c59fa5 vc_custom_1607629567903 lqd-unit-animation-done" style="opacity: 1;">
         <span>
         <span class="btn-txt">Enroll Now</span>
         <span class="btn-icon"><i class="icon-arrows_right"></i></span>            </span>
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
```

**JS File**

```
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("radio");
  var selected = Array.from(radios).find(radio => radio.checked);
  document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = selected.value;
  
  var myself = document.getElementById('m').checked;
  var MS = document.getElementById('ms').checked;
  var MC = document.getElementById('mc').checked;
  var MF = document.getElementById('mf').checked;

  if (myself === true) {
     document.getElementById('link').href = "https://www.1enrollment.com/order/checkout.cfm?id=575916&pdid=30894&benefitid=51&bSmoker=0&step=2&periodid=1";
  }
  else if (MS === true) {
      document.getElementById('link').href = "https://www.1enrollment.com/order/checkout.cfm?id=575916&pdid=30894&benefitid=41&bSmoker=0&step=2&periodid=1";
  }
    else if (MC === true) {
      document.getElementById('link').href = "https://www.1enrollment.com/order/checkout.cfm?id=575916&pdid=30894&benefitid=117&bSmoker=0&step=2&periodid=1";
  }
    else {
      document.getElementById('link').href = "https://www.1enrollment.com/order/checkout.cfm?id=575916&pdid=30894&benefitid=146&bSmoker=0&step=2&periodid=1";
  }
}

function setSmokerPrice() {
  var smoker = document.getElementById('smoker').checked;
    if (smoker === true) {
      document.getElementById('myselfSmoke').innerHTML = '$394/mo.';
      document.getElementById('msSmoke').innerHTML = '$714/mo.';
      document.getElementById('mcSmoke').innerHTML = '$714/mo.';
      document.getElementById('mfSmoke').innerHTML = '$974/mo.';

    document.getElementById('m').value = '394';
    document.getElementById('ms').value = '714';
    document.getElementById('mc').value = '714';
    document.getElementById('mf').value = '974';

         var myself = document.getElementById('m').checked;
  var MS = document.getElementById('ms').checked;
  var MC = document.getElementById('mc').checked;
  var MF = document.getElementById('mf').checked;
console.log(myself);
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("radio");
    var selected = Array.from(radios).find(radio => radio.checked);
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = selected.value;
  }
  else {
         document.getElementById('myselfSmoke').innerHTML = '$319/mo.';
      document.getElementById('msSmoke').innerHTML = '$639/mo.';
      document.getElementById('mcSmoke').innerHTML = '$639/mo.';
      document.getElementById('mfSmoke').innerHTML = '$899/mo.';
  }
  
}

function setMedicalSharePrice() {
 var medicalShare = document.getElementById('sayNoToPlus').checked;
 if (medicalShare === true) {
       document.getElementById('smoker').disabled = true;
          document.getElementById('smoker').checked = false;


    document.getElementById('myselfSmoke').innerHTML = '$125/mo.';
    document.getElementById('msSmoke').innerHTML = '$240/mo.';
    document.getElementById('mcSmoke').innerHTML = '$240/mo.';
    document.getElementById('mfSmoke').innerHTML = '$365/mo.';
  
  document.getElementById('m').value = '125';
  document.getElementById('ms').value = '240';
  document.getElementById('mc').value = '240';
  document.getElementById('mf').value = '365';
  
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("radio");
  var selected = Array.from(radios).find(radio => radio.checked);
  document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = selected.value;
 }
    else {
          document.getElementById('smoker').disabled = false;

         document.getElementById('myselfSmoke').innerHTML = '$319/mo.';
      document.getElementById('msSmoke').innerHTML = '$639/mo.';
      document.getElementById('mcSmoke').innerHTML = '$639/mo.';
      document.getElementById('mfSmoke').innerHTML = '$899/mo.';
  }
}
```

Any advice would be great, thanks!

Comment: Your "JavaScript Snippet" link doesn't point to any source code, it just takes you to a website. Please include all relevant code right in your question and don't link to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. You don't need Codepens or Fiddles. Just create a stack snippet (the `{}` button while you are editing a question) right in your question.

Comment: I added the HTML and the Javascript, the CSS couldn't be added because it went over the character limit